# How could codesign work in Cent OS

Tags: ios

I've tried to resign some enterprise applications over MacOS by using some kind of tool named "iResign", it worked. When I try to use it in Linux, I just got an error that codesign doesn't exists.

Now I know codesign is just for MacOS. But I really need to resign my app in CentOS, so that I can install and open it automatically by using MDM commands.

How can I resign any .ipa in CentOS? Anything could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tool called [isign](https://github.com/saucelabs/isign) you can use that is open source and runs on Linux.